# How to Determine Correct `taxonomy_id` for Etsy's `createDraftListing` API?

Tags: typescript, axios, etsy

I am currently developing an application that integrates with Etsy's API, specifically using the `createDraftListing` endpoint to post new listings. My application focuses on digital downloads, and I am having trouble determining the correct `taxonomy_id` to use for these types of products. [DOCS](https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference#tag/ShopListing)

Here's a snippet of my code for creating a draft listing:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const listingData = {
  quantity: 9,
  title: "Example Title",
  description: "Example Description",
  price: 19.99,
  who_made: "i_did",
  when_made: "2020_2024",
  taxonomy_id: ???, // Unsure what to put here
  type: "download",
};

axios.post('https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/listings', listingData, {
  headers: {
    'x-api-key': 'Your-Etsy-API-Key',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Your-OAuth-Token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error posting to Etsy:', error);
});
```

I am aware that `taxonomy_id` is essential for ensuring the listing appears in the correct category on Etsy, but I'm not sure how to find the appropriate ID for digital downloads. I've looked through the Etsy API documentation but haven't found clear guidance on this.

**My questions are:**

- How do I retrieve the list of available `taxonomy_ids` from Etsy's API?
- What is the best way to determine the appropriate `taxonomy_id` for digital download products?
- Is there an example or a resource that shows the mapping of product types to their respective taxonomy IDs on Etsy?

Any help or pointers to the relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Send a `GET` request to this URL: https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/seller-taxonomy/nodes

Use your `api-key` with a `x-api-key` header and the value. You'll receive a large list of taxonomies which you can use. Here is a small amount of the taxonomy code as an example:

```
{
"count": 15,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "name": "Accessories",
        "parent_id": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "level": 2,
                "name": "Belts & Suspenders",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "level": 3,
                        "name": "Belt Buckles",
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "children": [],
                        "full_path_taxonomy_ids": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "level": 3,
                        "name": "Belts",
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "children": [],
                        "full_path_taxonomy_ids": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            4
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "level": 3,
                        "name": "Suspenders",
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "children": [],
                        "full_path_taxonomy_ids": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            5
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "full_path_taxonomy_ids": [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            },
```